# Second Order Passive Low Pass Filter RC Circuit Design

Tags: noise, low-pass, homework, passive-filter, lti-system

I'm learning about Second Order Passive low Pass Filter RC Circuit for my homework.
I need to create a circuit with a specification that has a 1 kHz cut off frequency.

I quickly learned on how to solve for the cut off frequency and the components values that I need in First Order Passive Low Pass Filter but I am having trouble when it comes to Second Order.

How will I design a circuit with a specification of 1 kHz cut off frequency in Second Order Passive Low Pass Filter? I got an answer of 1 kHz Cut Off Frequency on the First Order of the Filter but will I still get 1 kHz cut off frequency if I use the same value? Please show on how to solve the circuit so that I could understand. I haven't seen any tutorials on the internet regarding this matter that is clear or easy to understand.

[image: This is my circuit of second order filter.]

Comment: Sorry, we won't do your homework for you. You need to demonstrate that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself. **Show us all of your work.**. Then ask a **specific** question.

Comment: Just so you don't have the wrong expectations, any passive only RC filter, no matter the order, will never have complex conjugate poles, which means classic designs such as Butterworth, Chebyshev, Bessel, etc, will not be available. If done right, the impulse response should converge towards a gaussian, but only after many, many sections (think a hundred or more).

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the input impedance of the circuit which is to be connected to the output (or simply, the load impedance) should have been given but I'm assuming it to be very high or simply infinite.

I will not solve the circuit for you. I'll only show you a way of solving it:

- Use Thevenin equivalents to simplify the circuit. I'm sure you know how to make a Thevenin conversion.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuiVlW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- The circuit turned into a simple circuit with three series-connected components. Since the current sourced by the input flows through all of them, you can easily get what the output voltage will be.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJDtHT.png)</sup>

- Derive the transfer function by dividing the output voltage to input voltage. Be careful, the input is not the Thevenin voltage.

$$
H(s)=\frac{something \ \ something}{s^2+2\zeta\omega_n+\omega_n^2}
$$

From here, using \$s=j\omega\$, make the necessary analysis to obtain a -3dB loss at 1kHz with a rate of -40dB/decade. The rest is yours.

Answer (score 0):

> *I haven't seen any tutorials on the internet regarding this matter
> that is clear or easy to understand.*

and

> *I learned how to solve the cut off frequency and the
> components values that I need in First Order Passive Low Pass Filter
> but I am having trouble when it comes to Second Order.*

Here are few clues (equal value resistors and capacitors): -

- Solve the transfer function (TF) of the whole circuit.
- The TF is \$\dfrac{1}{1 - \omega^2C^2R^2 + j3\omega CR}\$ if you are interested.
- Convert the TF from complex numbers to a magnitude value and equate to \$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}\$.
- \$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}\$ represents the amplitude magnitude at the -3 dB point.
- When you do that, you find this: \$\hspace{0.5cm}\omega^4 C^4 R^4 + 7\omega^2 C^2 R^2 - 1 = 0\$
- Solve for \$\omega^2\$ in the usual math way (quadratic formula): -

$$\omega^2 = \dfrac{-7C^2 R^2 \pm \sqrt{49C^4 R^4 + 4C^4R^4}}{2C^4 R^4}$$

- Then drill down to get: \$\omega^2 = \dfrac{1}{C^2 R^2}\times \text{0.140054945}\$

I'm sure you can convert that plain ordinary \$\omega\$ by taking the square root.

And, if you plug your values in for R and C you get a 3dB cut-off point of 372.26 Hz. The single stage cut-off frequency was 994.7 kHz so, changing the CR time constant in the same proportion is the route to take.

Basically, you need to start fiddling with the C value to bring \$f_C\$ up towards 1 kHz.